# Zurb Foundation dropdown menu doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I got this error when clicking on my dropdown menu on the zurb top bar:

```
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
```

Here is my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require_tree .

$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

and in my view (slim template):

```
  nav class="top-bar"
    ul class="title-area"
      li class="name"
        h1
          a href="#" My Project
      li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"
        a href="#" Menu
    section class="top-bar-section"
      ul class="left"
        li class="divider"
        li class="divider hide-for-small"
      ul class="right"
        li class="divider show-for-medium-and-up"
          - if current_user
            li class="has-dropdown"
              a href="#"
                = "Logged in as #{current_user.email}"
              ul class="dropdown"
                li
                  a href="#"
                    ' First link in dropdown
            li
              = link_to "Log Out", logout_path
          - else
            li
              = link_to t("layout.login"), login_path
            li
              = link_to t("layout.signup"), signup_path
```

The dropdown menu doesn't work (it doesn't appear when clicking or hovering)

Comment: @BlueSkies Zurb = the Foundation CSS framework made by Zurb.

Comment: Anyway, if the error is coming from zurb's code, then it looks to me like their approach to older IE compatibility doesn't favor `.preventDefault()` as it arguably should. You may want to file a bug report with them if so.

Comment: How can I check that it is the case?

Comment: @sidney the warning message you received has nothing to do with the dropdown not working. Ignore it.

Comment: @sidney which version of Foundation or you using - 4 or 5?

Comment: @janfoeh, ok; I use foundation-rails (5.0.2.0), the fifth version

Comment: If I see correctly, you are trying to use a dropdown in the top-bar navigation. Is that right? In that case, please show us the full top bar markup.

Comment: @janfoeh, I edited the question, with the full and real code of the nav.
I can see "Logged in as ...", it is displayed. But can't click on it and display the menu

Comment: I've updated my answer - you were missing a `data` attribute.

Comment: @janfoeh, Oh I'm so glad, thanks dude ! I copied past a foundation4 code and lost almost more than 2 hours of real work for this.
And lulz, someone redirected my first post and downvoted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dropdown seems to be not working because you forgot the data-topbar attribute on the nav element. The Topbar javascript code never ran.

Comment: Thanks I already knew that, but the thing is that I don't get the dropdown working

Answer (score 0):

you need to add jquery.js, foundation.js and foundation.topbar.js in sequence.

example:

```
top - <script src="<?php echo $resources;?>plugins/foundation/js/jquery.js"></script>
2nd file - foundation.js 
3rd file - foundation.topbar.js
```

foundation.topbar.js AFTER the foundation.js file.

Comment: thanks anyways, but I already did that, and I fixed the problem with another post :)
+ I don't use php

Answer (score -1):

This is not an error, this is a jQuery issue, which appears when your anchor's href attribute is prevented to be followed with e.preventDefault();

Comment: Thanks, how can I do to fix this issue then please?